# From column to total up all value and make a new row name 'TOTAL'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is an original table from csv:

```
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Access SSID   | Radio Frequencies   |   User Count | Total Traffic   |
|---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------|
| SIS-OPEN      | 2.4G                |          378 | 144.28 GB       |
| nan           | 5G                  |          361 | 142.59 GB       |
| SIS-STAFF     | 2.4G                |            1 | 32.63 MB        |
| nan           | 5G                  |           10 | 2.20 GB         |
| SIS-STUDENT   | 2.4G                |           88 | 31.64 GB        |
| nan           | 5G                  |          136 | 37.96 GB        |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

My result and I'm tried using this:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(axis = 0)
```

```
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Access SSID   | Radio Frequencies   |   User Count | Total Traffic                                     |
|---------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------|
| SIS-OPEN      | 2.4G                |          378 | 144.28 GB                                         |
| nan           | 5G                  |          361 | 142.59 GB                                         |
| SIS-STAFF     | 2.4G                |            1 | 32.63 MB                                          |
| nan           | 5G                  |           10 | 2.20 GB                                           |
| SIS-STUDENT   | 2.4G                |           88 | 31.64 GB                                          |
| nan           | 5G                  |          136 | 37.96 GB                                          |
| Total         | 2.4G5G2.4G5G2.4G5G  |          974 | 144.28 GB142.59 GB32.63 MB2.20 GB31.64 GB37.96 GB |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

My expected result should be:

```
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Access SSID   | Radio Frequencies   |   User Count | Total Traffic   |
|---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------|
| SIS-OPEN      | 2.4G                |          378 | 144.28 GB       |
| nan           | 5G                  |          361 | 142.59 GB       |
| SIS-STAFF     | 2.4G                |            1 | 32.63 MB        |
| nan           | 5G                  |           10 | 2.20 GB         |
| SIS-STUDENT   | 2.4G                |           88 | 31.64 GB        |
| nan           | 5G                  |          136 | 37.96 GB        |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| TOTAL         |                     |          974 |                 |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for only numeric columns:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.select_dtypes('number').sum(axis = 0)
```

If need also replace missing values to empty strings add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.loc['Total'] = (df.select_dtypes('number')
                     .sum(axis = 0)
                     .reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=''))
print (df)
            Radio Frequencies  User Count Total Traffic
Access SSID                                            
SIS-OPEN                 2.4G         378     144.28 GB
NaN                        5G         361     142.59 GB
SIS-STAFF                2.4G           1      32.63 MB
NaN                        5G          10       2.20 GB
SIS-STUDENT              2.4G          88      31.64 GB
NaN                        5G         136      37.96 GB
Total                                 974
```